# Running Total by Group SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, cumulative-sum

I have a table in an Oracle db that has the following fields of interest: Location, Product, Date, Amount.  I would like to write a query that would get a running total of amount by Location, Product, and Date.  I put an example table below of what I would like the results to be.

I can get a running total but I can't get it to reset when I reach a new Location/Product.  This is the code I have thus far, any help would be much appreciated, I have a feeling this is a simple fix.

```
select a.*, sum(Amount) over (order by Location, Product, Date) as Running_Amt
from Example_Table a

+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Location | Product | Date      | Amount     |Running_Amt |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| A        | aa      | 1/1/2013  | 100        | 100        |
| A        | aa      | 1/5/2013  | -50        | 50         |
| A        | aa      | 5/1/2013  | 100        | 150        |
| A        | aa      | 8/1/2013  | 100        | 250        |
| A        | bb      | 1/1/2013  | 500        | 500        |
| A        | bb      | 1/5/2013  | -100       | 400        |
| A        | bb      | 5/1/2013  | -100       | 300        |
| A        | bb      | 8/1/2013  | 250        | 550        |
| C        | aa      | 3/1/2013  | 550        | 550        |
| C        | aa      | 5/5/2013  | -50        | 600        |
| C        | dd      | 10/3/2013 | 999        | 999        |
| C        | dd      | 12/2/2013 | 1          | 1000       |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, I think I have figured it out.

```
select a.*, sum(Amount) over (partition by Location, Product order by Date) as Running_Amt
from Example_Table a
```

Answer (score 7):

from Advanced SQL Functions in Oracle 10g book, it has this example.

```
SELECT dte "Date", location, receipts,
SUM(receipts) OVER(ORDER BY dte
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
AND CURRENT ROW) "Running total"
FROM store
WHERE dte < '10-Jan-2006'
ORDER BY dte, location
```

Answer (score -3):

I could type out all the answer or send you to where I learned it. :)

Check this out, it explains exactly what you are trying to do.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server

Comment: You don't find the article that explains how to partition the data useful? Although the answer is partitioning.

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but I think there is definitely room for improvement.  Maybe consider adding more context/content - there seems to be a consensus on SO that [links alone are not sufficient for a good answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad).

Comment: As an aside, this link may have been more appropriate as a comment instead of an answer... but unfortunately you need 50 rep for that.  If you're like me and you thought that was lame, then check out [this question about it on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), which gives the limitation some motivation, and also suggests some ways to write a great answer :D

Comment: The linked article is for SQL Server. Oracle has a much more efficient way of doing this using a window function.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to criticize my answer which solved the problem. Many thanks for mentioning that oracle has a more efficient way but not bothering to answer the question. It would have been more helpful if you actually provided some instruction on your efficient way. The answer I referenced works in oracle the same way it does in SQL Server.