# Decreasing running total in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cumulative-sum

Table A

```
Week    Column_1   Column_2
0       9          92
1       0          84
2       1          84
3       4          83
```

The result I want is

```
Week Column_1  Column_2  Remaining
0    9         92        83
1    0         84        83
2    1         84        82
3    4         83        78
```

So, if you notice. I want to calculate the **Remaining** as *Column_2 - Column_1* for week 0 and after week 0 I want to calculate the **Remaining** as *Remaining - Column_1*

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Total by Group SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155401/running-total-by-group-sql-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT a.*,
       SUM (CASE
              WHEN a.week = 0 THEN column_2 - column_1
              ELSE -column_1
            END)
         over (
           ORDER BY week )
FROM   tablea a;
```